# JPA failing (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException)

Tags: java, jpa

I have a webservice that fails for apparently no reason. Sometimes it executes and sometimes it provides this error which i can't seem to figure out since the query actually makes sense...

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You have attempted to set a value of type class org.models.Employees for parameter currentEmployeeID with expected type of class org.models.Employees from query string SELECT b.carID FROM Cars b WHERE b.currentEmployeeID = :currentEmployeeID .
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.setParameterInternal(QueryImpl.java:932)
```

In the typed query,

```
Employees emp = new Employees(1)

TypedQuery<Integer> query = em.createQuery("SELECT b.carID FROM Cars b WHERE b.currentEmployeeID = :currentEmployeeID", Integer.class);
            query.setParameter("currentEmployeeID",emp);
```

As i said sometimes it works. It fails continuously sometimes when i restart the service.

If i said the currentEmployeeID as integer and not object employee it will provide a more clear error which i understand why..(something like, i am attempting to set value of type integer for parameter.......)

Comment: Is type of `currentEmployeeID` is `Employees`, from naming it seems some ID & not entity; why you don't use keys in query instead of whole object comparison.

Comment: @NayanWadekar An example will be ? CurrentEmloyeeID is a foreign key in car table.

Comment: Then why are you setting entity instead of key, its unclear what you are trying to do; why you just provide what it requires. Query would be - `SELECT b.carID FROM Cars b WHERE b.cars_key = :employee_key` & set parameter value accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the parameter passed to the method is of type Employees when you're waiting for an identifier. Try the following :

```
Employees emp = new Employees(1)

TypedQuery<Integer> query = em.createQuery("SELECT b.carID FROM Cars b WHERE b.currentEmployeeID = :currentEmployeeID", Integer.class);
            query.setParameter("currentEmployeeID",emp.getId());
```

Answer (score 0):

`EntityManager.createQuery()` expects an JPQL query (not an SQL query).
Try the following:

```
em.createQuery("SELECT b.carID FROM Cars b INNER JOIN b.currentEmployee e WHERE e.id = :currentEmployeeID", Integer.class);
```

Comment: Sincerely I doubt it works: `currentEmployeeID` is the name of the DB column and not of the persistent Java property.